# A book series about an engineer sent back in time to medieval times

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I am trying to remember a book series where the main character, a male engineer, is sent back in time to medieval Europe (it is a historical setting with no magic) and applies his knowledge, in the style of a Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's court.  It was a multi-book series published after 1960, and in one of the books he makes an aircraft.  It was not a very well known series.  At least one of the books' titles was in the format "The Blank Knight" or "The Knight of Blank".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This sounds like [The Cross-time Engineer](https://www.goodreads.com/author/list/6507048.Leo_Frankowski) by Leo Frankowski. #4 in the series is [The Flying Warlord](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/555870.The_Flying_Warlord); #2 is [The High-Tech Knight](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1197497.The_High_Tech_Knight).

If I remember correctly it is inspired by [Lord Kalvan of Otherwhen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Kalvan_of_Otherwhen).

Comment: And book 2 is called "The High-Tech Knight"

Comment: Fair warning that a lot of fans of the series felt that the quality dropped after the fourth book.

Comment: Its Leo Frankowski, but otherwise right on.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots How often do authors manage to retain the same quality for a series of eight or nine books?

Comment: @InTheAbsenceOfFear: True. I mainly felt like the stakes changed massively when it went from "Conrad brings modern technology through intelligent use of modern design" to "Time travelers cave in and just make everyone resistant to all diseases" to "Conrad survives a shipwreck by suckling on the breast of his decapitated servant".

Comment: @InTheAbsenceOfFear: Anne McCaffrey managed to maintain consistent literary quality over fourteen *Pern* books mainly by setting low expectations from the beginning.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri and they won Hugos!

Answer (score 3):

As already answered, this is probably Leo Frankowski's Cross Time Engineer/Conrad Stargard series. But if it isn't, then it could also be a much older book:

[L. Sprague de Camp's *Lest Darkness Fall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lest_Darkness_Fall)

I seem to recall that this story sends the modern man (an archaeologist, rather than an engineer) back to ancient Rome, but if you liked one, you'll probably like the other.

Answer (score -2):

Might be "A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court" by Mark Twain too. Has the plot you described. An oldie but a goodie.

Comment: [AlanT's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/262968/122024) (of _The Cross-Time Engineer_ by Leo Frankowski) was already [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by the OP, as denoted by the green check mark to the left of it. Also, the [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/262967/122024) cites _A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court_ as being similar in style to the story the OP was looking for, which would suggest it's not the actual story. Not to mention that that protagonist in _A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court_ is not an engineer.